# situations in which copying a string is absolutely necessary

Tags: string, swift

Apple documentation says:
“Swift’s copy-by-default String behavior ensures that when a function or method passes you a String value, it is clear that you own that exact String value, regardless of where it came from. You can be confident that the string you are passed will not be modified unless you modify it yourself.

Behind the scenes, Swift’s compiler optimizes string usage so that actual copying takes place only when absolutely necessary. This means you always get great performance when working with strings as value types.”

So, maybe a dumb question, but still, what are the situations in which copying a string is absolutely necessary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you pass a string to a function, or assign it to another variable, the semantics say that Swift makes a copy.

In reality, Swift just keeps a pointer to the original string, so there is really only one copy in memory.  It becomes necessary to make a copy when either the original string is modified, or the new copy is modified.  At that time, it becomes necessary to create the distinct copy.

Consider the following code:

```
var str = "this is my string"
var str2 = str  // no copy is made here even though str2 is a copy of str
str2 += "!"     // now a copy is made so str2 can be modified
```

The advantage of this is you can pass a large string to a function without incurring the overhead of actually copying the memory.  You can pass the same string from function to function, and if none of them modify it, you will only have one copy in memory.